# Tensorflow SyntaxError with python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow to my Linux systems (Linuxmint) with Python 3.5 using pip installation with CPU support. After the installation is done; to validate my installation I try to run the following script

python3

```
>import tensorflow as tf
```

the result is the following:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
>       from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
>       from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygoogle/google.py", line 118
>       %(__credits__)s""" % globals()
>                        ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Can someone please help on the topic?

Comment: Check your package versions.... what version of protobuf are you using? Are you using venvs or installing to your os?

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading `tensorflow` 1.3.0 to 1.4.0 I encountered this error. to solve it, I check different steps :

```
sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow-gpu
sudo pip3 uninstall protobuf
sudo pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.3.0
sudo pip3 install protobuf==3.3.0
```

but the error was not resolved. finally, I uninstalled `pygoogle`

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pygoogle
```

and it works! Hope it will work for you too.