# Whenever I do pip3 freeze or any pip3 command in my mac terminal, it raises a syntax error

Tags: python, pip

Usually, pip3 works normally, but after installing tenser flow using pip, for some reason pip is not working anymore. For example, I did `pip freeze` to get my packages, but it came up with this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import HAS_TLS, is_url, path_to_url, url_to_path
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import indent_log
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3079, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3123, in _initialize_master_working_set
    for dist in working_set
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3123, in <genexpr>
    for dist in working_set
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2633, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2170, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2105, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygoogle/google.py", line 118
    %(__credits__)s""" % globals()
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But when I do `pip2 freeze` it works completely normal.

I'm not sure if tenserflow is causing this, but it started happening after I installed it.
I have a mac os sierra 10.13.4, and did the commands on my terminal. I am using python 3.6.6 . Is there any way to fix this? I also tried uninstalling tensor flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow SyntaxError with python 3.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875138/tensorflow-syntaxerror-with-python-3-5-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the cause of the problem is a Python 2.7 module somehow getting installed into python 3.6 folder. The guilty module is pygoogle. Uninstalling that may work. See:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12390/

[Tensorflow SyntaxError with python 3.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875138/tensorflow-syntaxerror-with-python-3-5-2)

Comment: Thank you! I solved it by doing rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygoogle